# magento ce 2.0 supported extension 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-2.0

i developed project in magento ce version 2.0 , also some addition feature purpose i need to add extension of reward point for money transfer extension.

so i decide purchase

http://demo.magestore.com/reward-points/api/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/6f37baae6c7590087136604a2fbcc9a7/

but problem is that this version is ce 1.9 and i installed magento ce 2.0 version setup so after purchase this 1.9 extension of reward point work on my magento version 2.0  if you have any idea then share to me....

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 is a complete rewrite, or replatform as they call it, there is no way to use the same extensions or themes in 1.x and 2.x, they need to be rewritten for Magento 2.

There are tools that help developers converting their code but a fully automated solution is not possible.

Comment: thanks for replied, don't mind i converting code  but work on properly?? insort not more issue occerence

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you.

Comment: means magento ce  2.0 supported 1.9 extension

Comment: The answer is no